# Android: add two or more fragments to the same backstack state

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, state, fragment-backstack

I have a main activity with a [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) container where i load different fragments using the[FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html). 
Let's say i load fragment1 and fragment2 with two transactions. In case of back button pressed, i want to return to the state when both fragment1 and fragment2 were not loaded. Is this possible? 
I've tried to use the same name in the addToBackStack() method:

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment1).addToBackStack("SameState").commit();

mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_main, fragment2).addToBackStack("SameState").commit();
```

but this doesn't work. If i press the back button fragment2 disappears first, then pressing again fragment1 goes away too. Any suggestion?

Comment: @DeeV if i do this way the fragment2 is still alive (rendered)

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  It won't include it to the back stack.  I think the way you may have to go about it is add both to the container together, then rather than add, you hide/unhide fragment2 on the second commit.  That way, when you press "back", both will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.activity_main,fragment1)
 .addToBackStack(null)
 .commit();

getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // Pop the first transaction
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.activity_main,fragment2)
 .addToBackStack(null)
 .commit();
```

At this point, when you press the back button, it will simply revert the last transaction (fragment2 replacing).

Comment: Tried this but the app crash...and without an error in the log i don't know why